# Bluetooth communication between iOS and RPi 3

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm currently working on a project that needs communication between a Raspberry Pi 3 and an iOS device.

I have achieved to pair the two devices and connect them (im using RxBluetoothKit for that) but when it comes to communication I just cant find any ressources to even guide me.

In fact I need to send a string from the RPi 3 to the iOS device and send a string from the iPhone to the RPi3

Does anyone know where i could find some help ?
I code in Swift for the app.

Comment: You should refer to the CoreBluetooth programming guide and framework references for details on using Bluetooth Low Energy from an iOS app

Comment: Check out this post. It covers the basics of CoreBluetooth. https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor